# How to access props of a component in vue from typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to access the props in my vue component (child) below from another vue component (Parent). I am basically trying to reset the `:selected` value to null after the user selects an option from the dropdown menu.

```
 <template>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" v-if="showMenu">
      <li v-for="option in options">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { directive as onClickaway } from "vue-clickaway";
export default {
  directives: {
    onClickaway
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
      placeholderText: "Please select an item"
    };
  },
  props: {
    selected: {},
    placeholder: [String],
  },
  },

  methods: {
    updateOptions(option) {
      this.showMenu = false;
      this.$emit("input", this.selectedOption);
    },
  }
};

</script>
```

Comment: What does the code for `updateOption()` in the parent component look like?

Comment: @LannyBose oh, theres no code for it in the parent component, its from the child component.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `onColourSelection`

Comment: @LannyBose  `public onColourSelection(val: any) { this.colourId = val.id; }` this is pretty much it,  `colourOptions` are the colours obtained from the API as an array.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice in your parent template is that you're hard-coding the `selected` prop to `{}` which means it will never change. In addition, you're immediately throwing away the selected prop in the child's mounted hook with:

```
  mounted() {
    this.selectedOption = this.selected;
  }
```

...which means even if you change the prop from the parent, it won't do anything.

I'm going to suggest a refactoring of your code to use `v-model` in a way that the Dropdown never actually stores the selected value, but rather relies on the parent to store state ([link to Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)).

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <dropdown
    // other options skipped for clarity

    v-model="selected"
  ></dropdown>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected: undefined
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you see in the Vue docs, `v-model` is just a convention for passing a prop called `value` and listening to an event called `input`. So in your child, you need to refactor slightly. Specifically, we're going to get rid of your intermediary value `selectedOption`:

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  <!-- other divs hidden for clarity -->
  
  <input
    @click="toggleMenu()"
    v-model="value[attr]" // I am unsure that this is the right choice 
    type="text">

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" v-if="showMenu">
      <li v-for="option in options">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="updateOption(option)">{{ option[attr] }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
      placeholderText: "Please select an item"
    };
  },
  props: {
    value: {}, // changed from selected
    attr: String,
  },

  methods: {
    updateOption(option) {
      this.showMenu = false;
      this.$emit('input', this.selectedOption);
    },
  }
};

</script>
```

The only place I'm unsure of your intended behavior is in your Child `<input>` tag. You had a v-model for the input, but it doesn't look like you're doing anything when someone types into that input (such as searching the color names, or whatever). Since typing in that input doesn't currently do anything. It may make more sense to make it a `<div>` that **looks** like an input but isn't actually type-able. Perhaps...

```
  <div @click="toggleMenu()">
    {{ value[attr] }}
  </div>
```

Comment: oo, may i ask is it necessary to remove a few of the methods of the dropdown component and also in removing some properties of the input tag. Ill give this a shot right now!

Comment: Sorry no. I removed a bunch of stuff just to make it easier to highlight where I changed. Stuff like your placeholder, required, etc. all looked ok.

Comment: The undefined makes sense since (I'm assuming) when you start the form there isn't a selection in the parent component. Perhaps the `value[attr]` should be wrapped in an `if (value) { }` to prevent render errors on first load

Comment: And yes, I removed the concept of `selectedOption` entirely. The child is no longer separately storing the selection. It's relying entirely on the prop `selected`